# curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 443: Connection refused

Tags: webhooks

**#curl -k https://localhost/api/v1/webhooks/sample -d '{"foo": "bar", "name": "st2"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'X-Auth-Token: put_token_here'**

curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 443: Connection refused

Comment: Welcome! This question is a bit light on detail. Adding what you’re trying to connect to would make this question easier to answer.

Answer (score 1):

This most likely means that there is nothing listening.

Are you sure that the port is 443? It's common to run at a different port when developing and running websites/apis in debug. The port could be 44301, for example.